# != operator condition usage in c#

Tags: c#, c++, operators, conditional-statements

I know that in C++ you can do this kind of declarations:

```
size = 8 * (x % 8 != 0);
```

What would be the equivalent in C#? Do I have to use an "if"? Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you tried to see what's behavior of above statement in C#?

Comment: could you explain what this is attempting to do? is this trying to round up to the nearest multiple of 8?

Comment: Always consider to produce unserstandable code, no matter on which language you are. I have to admit I´m not sure I understand what the code should do. Does it multiply 8 by one or zero depending on if `x` can can be devided by 8?

Comment: I'd assume that would be the same result as `x % 8 == 0 ? 0 : 8`

Comment: Again, I'll stress. This community is not a code translation service. Post your effort first.

Comment: Why would you *want* to do it this way in C++?

Comment: Sorry for the bad code, actually is not code I made. Just focus in the statement inside the parentheses, it says like "if the remainder after dividing the first operand by the second is different than 0, then multiply by 8." I guess it assumes if the condition is not true, the number will be then 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you can use the [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
var size = 8 * (x % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Or even simpler:

```
var size = (x % 8 != 0) ? 8 : 0;
```

Comment: Then you can clearly remove the multiplication. `size = x % 8 != 0 ? 8 : 0`